# Can Ainz Oal gown make Clones of himself?

Tags: overlord

***(warning! spoiler alert)***: In the Final episode of overlord season 3 (Episode 13), something really tricky happened and it kinda blew my mind. Ainz Oal gown was in his warrior form (Aka Momon) and he was talking to Albedo about how he wanted to defend E-rantel from The magic King (Ainz himself) and then just as they were about to fight, Ainz Oal Gown in his true form landed close to Albedo in order to form a truce.

I don't really understand what happened in this scene because momon is ainz in his warrior form, so that leads me to the question. Does Ainz have some magical spell that allows him to make clones of himself? if not then how could there be 2 Ainz at the same time and place. Its pretty mind blowing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandora's Actor has the ability to disguise himself as Ainz and others.

> As a higher-tier Doppelgänger, he has an ability to mimic a player based on their appearance as well as their ability.

He already did that in episode 10 of season 2 while meeting Sebas and Tuare.
It is reasonable to assume that the same happened in episode 13.

[Source](http://overlordmaruyama.wikia.com/wiki/Pandora%27s_Actor)